# How to get the operation Links in my own EntityListBuilder

Tags: 8, entities

I use the Symfony framework the first time and goes through several tutorials to create an own entity type. https://www.daggerhart.com/drupal-8-custom-entities-bundles/ or https://www.daggerhart.com/drupal-8-custom-entities-bundles/

Now runs all very well, but I didn`t get the operation links(edit/delete) in every row for the saved content. There is only a devel link. If I moved directly to the content like www.exapmle/mytest/{id}/edit or www.exapmle/mytest/{id}/delete I can saw the content, edit the content, delete the content and the tabs are shown. So I think I have the permission for that.

Any ideas?

mytest.routing.yml:

```
entity.mytest.delete_test:
  path: '/tested/{mytest}/delete'
  defaults:
    _entity_form: mytest.delete
    _title: 'Delete Test'
  requirements:
    _entity_access: 'mytest.delete'
```

mytest.php in src/Entity

```
* @ContentEntityType(
*   id = "mytest",
*   links = {
*     "canonical" = "/tested/{mytest}",
*     "delete-shop" = "/tested/{mytest}/delete",
*     "collection" = "/tested"
*   },
* )
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after I found the documentation at [drupal documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityListBuilder.php/function/EntityListBuilder%3A%3AgetDefaultOperations/8.2.x) I get it! The naming of the link list must be:

```
* @ContentEntityType(
*   id = "mytest",
*   links = {
*     "canonical" = "/tested/{mytest}",
*     "delete-form" = "/tested/{mytest}/delete", // EDIT! 
*     "collection" = "/tested"
*   },
* )
```

That's all!